# My server won't serve new version of my images

Tags: image, apache, refresh

I'm not sure if this is the exact community to be asking, but...

I'm building a website and have had to make changes to the images it uses as CSS backgrounds, but for some reason when I upload the image and replace the old one, the old one still gets served.

- I can view the new image via my FTP client, so it is in fact on the server
- Clearing the browser cache doesn't help
- Of course, changing the name of the image and it's respective CSS works
- Add `?v=1` to the end of the image doesn't work
- I'm using a MediaTemple Grid Server for this project
- It's all same-domain

Any ideas? I'm so lost.

Comment: Use server logs and browser debugging mode to find out what your browser is *really* asking for.

Comment: It could be some weird server side caching problem, perhaps you can restart your web server or find out how to clear it's cache.

Comment: Yea, when was the last time you've cleared your cache?

Comment: Found the culprit. I had CloudFlare enabled on my (gs) - it was the one caching everything. Big ups to MediaTemple support on that one.